# Plant identification - Dracena White stripes?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I've recently bought this plant but I don't know what it is. I googled with some image searches and it looks like Dracena White Stripes.

Does anyone have an idea what it is?

Thanks!

[Plant image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHD1D.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its more likely to be Dracaena sanderiana, which has the common name of ribbon plant (though that name is used for other plants too). The leaves on Dracaena White Stripe are usually broader and more closely spaced up the stem than D. sanderiana. Image here http://www.plantsrescue.com/dracaena-sanderiana/ - scroll down to the second image. You will see from the link that the plant commonly grown in water and known as Lucky Bamboo is also Dracaena sanderiana, but it can be grown, as you are doing, in a pot in soil, when it develops proper leaves rather than just being a bunch of stems with small leaves.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the one :). I saw from the link that it is a sensitive plant, to temperature and wind changes. I hope it will thrive though, it looks very nice.

Comment: At first, I thought drecaena deremensis http://www.indoor-plant-care.com/images/dracaena-deremensis-__0.jpg , but after looking at dozens of photos, I agree with dracaena sanderiana. This one looks exactly like yours: http://www.lundagershop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/580x580/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/_/5/_5925.jpg